# default tf.gradients in TensorFlow - total or partial derivatives?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

so I'm reading about tf.gradients() in the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) and I'm a bit confused.

I've seen people stating that the results of tf.gradients() are

> symbolic partial derivatives of sum of ys w.r.t. x in xs.

This is also what I was thinking first. But then the documentation describes one optional arguments of this function as follows:

> stop_gradients is a Tensor or a list of tensors to be considered constant with respect to all xs. These tensors will not be backpropagated through, as though they had been explicitly disconnected using stop_gradient. Among other things, this allows computation of partial derivatives as opposed to total derivatives.

So is it only possible to calculate the partial derivatives if I use 'stop_gradient' and otherwise the default values returned in a vector with len(xs) are total derivatives? Probably it's just my misunderstanding, it would be much appreciated if someone could elaborate on this a bit.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

According to the function documentation

> ... It returns a list of Tensor of length len(xs) where each tensor is the sum(dy/dx) for y in ys.

So this is exactly what you stated in the first part - each output tensor is a sum of ys *total* derivatives w.r.t. the corresponding x.

The documentation suggests use of `stop_gradients` parameter to calculate partial derivatives instead, i.e. tensors provided for this parameter are considered constant in the differentiation.